# Rails uniqueness validation on nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rails model that has attributes 'term' and 'section'.
I want a uniqueness constraint on these attributes, so I tried this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :term, scope: :section
```

This would only work when both 'term' and 'scope' were not nil, but I want the constraint to still apply when there are nil values. Looking at the ActiveRecord::Validations [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html), I saw that setting 'allow_nil' to false would prevent the skipping of validation when an a value is nil. But the default value for this option is already false.

I tried setting allow_nil to both false and true anyways, but there was no change in behavior. Does anyone know why I cannot get the validation to work when there are nil values?

Comment: What's the purpose of setting `:scope` to `:section` ?

Comment: @Ali the `term` must be unique for all records that have the same value for `section`.

Comment: @user2745175 try to update rails or specify the version you use. Your DB version might be useful too if rails update doesn't help. I just tested your case with Rails 4.1.6 & PG 9.1 and it works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add

```
validates_presence_of :term, :section
```

Comment: How does this allow nil values?

Comment: He wants to set `allow_nil` to false which apparently does not work as expected, so I figured this would achieve the desired effect. How did you understand the question?

Comment: This is not really what I want. I want the unique constraint to be on the combination of term and section. I don't want a unique constraint on them individually.EDIT: Oh I misread the suggestion. I cannot enforce presence of section. It should be able to be nil.

Comment: @user2745175: can `term` be nil too? Can they both be `nil`?

Comment: Only section can be nil

Answer (score 0):

"I want the unique constraint to be on the combination of term and section. I don't want a unique constraint on them individually."

That's cross-field validation; you'll need to build a custom validator (using validates_with).  [Read about that here.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html)

Comment: validates_uniqueness_of explicitly supports this functionality. There shouldn't be a need for a custom validator.

Comment: Except he wants nil values not to count against the uniqueness constraint.

Comment: ":allow_nil - If set to true, skips this validation if the attribute is nil (default is false)." That sounds to me like any null column value either is ignored or is not ignored with regards to the uniqueness constraint. It sounds like I must be reading it wrong? Does it mean instead that the validation is skipped if the main attribute (the one not in the scope) is nil? If that's the case, that's rather surprising since that's a lot less useful behavior :/.